# Calculate YoY market share change in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate YoY market share change for the top 5 brands of a larger dataset. Has anyone done this using a calculated field before?

Comment: Can you provide your data structure or sample data? There are different ways to calculate YoY so more information is needed.

Comment: table calculation will help you.  However if want a step wise solution, csv data or .twbx is required